# Probability of rolling 6 dice with 1,2 & 3

Tags: probability, dice

lets say all our dice is fair and the rules is we win if we got 1,2 or 3 and lose if we got 4,5 or 6. so the probability for 1 dice will be - 3/6 or 50% of winning/losing

how much the probability will be if we hv 6 dices and get a minimum of 3 winning dices(with faces 1, 2 or 3)?

look up on the net found something like this -
3/6 x 3/6 x 3/6 x 3/6 x 3/6 x 3/6 = 729/46656 or 1.5625% but thats not correct as we just need min.3 winning dices to consider a win

p/s - we think 9/216 also not correct

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have a success rate of $p=\frac{1}{2}$ per experiment, we do $n=6$ experiments and if $X$ counts the number of succeses ; we need $P(X \ge 3)$. $X$ is distributed according to a [binomial distibution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and so

$$P(X \ge 3) = \sum_{i=3}^6 \binom{i}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6 = \frac{1}{64} (20 + 15+ 6+1) = \frac{21}{32}$$

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. is it possible to use some basic/layman way to do this? would like to learn to do it ourself in case we need to do some modifications like using 5 dices etc.

for eg. 1/2 + 1/2....

thank you,

Comment: @aboka: if you want $i$ successes out of $n$ trials, (say $n$ dice) and the chance of a winning die (singular of dice is die!) would be $p$ instead of a half, then we can pick the $i$ winning dice from the $n$ in $\binom{n}{i}$ ways and then that particular sequence of winning and losing dice has chance $p^i(1-p)^{n-1}$ and there are $\binom{n}{i}$ such sequences, hence the form of the formula. You need to know about combinations and binomial coefficients in general. A small number of dice could be done by hand.

Comment: thanks alot thou still not understand how its done. will revise and hopefully learn 'how to fish' ourself :)

Answer (score 2):

Since the probability of winning when throwing dice with these rules is $\frac{1}{2}$, this can be equated to flipping a coin. Therefore, the question goes: When flipping a coin 6 times, what is the probability that there will be at least 3 Heads? (The probability of Heads is $\frac{1}{2}$)

The probability can be calculated like this:
$$
\begin{split}
P(\text{win}) &= P(3~\text{Heads}) + P(4~\text{Heads}) + P(5~\text{Heads})  +P(6~\text{Heads}) \\
&= {6 \choose 3} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3
 + {6 \choose 4} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^4\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2
 + {6 \choose 5} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^5\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^1
 + {6 \choose 6} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^0 \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^6 \left[{6 \choose 3} + {6 \choose 4} + {6 \choose 5} +{6 \choose 6}\right] \\
&= \frac{21}{32}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. is it possible to use some basic/layman way to do this? would like to learn to do it ourself in case we need to do some modifications like using 5 dices etc.

for eg. 1/2 + 1/2....

p/s - should post one and tag both of you guys, but not sure howto do that here

thank you,

Comment: hi, would like to point out tht you hv make it more simpler for us with your method, but we hv to choose @Henno answer as thou his is more complicated, but he answer first and it could be use if we are using 5 dices etc.

p/s- we would accept your answer too if the site let us choose more than one answer

thank you,

Comment: Hi and thank you. For learning this material, you could start by studying the Binomial distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution